# Avoid controls flickering while resizing them by code (.NET 4.6.1)

Tags: .net, winforms, resize, flicker, .net-4.6

I tried searching the site but didn't find any solution to my problem.
I would like to dynamically change my controls size inside the form and see only the final result without flickering issues.
I have written a short example to show you my problem:
When I press the "Bigger" button I would like to change my form from this:
[image: 1] 
to this:
[image: 2]
without seeing this:[image: 3]

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //DoubleBuffered = true; // Useless
    }

    private void Smaller_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (listBox1.Width > 100)
        {
            listBox1.Width -= 10;
            pictureBox1.Width -= 10;
            progressBar1.Width -= 10;
            textBox1.Width -= 10;
            Thread.Sleep(25);
        }
    }

    private void Bigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.SuspendLayout(); // Useless
        while(listBox1.Width < 700)
        {
            listBox1.Width += 10;
            pictureBox1.Width += 10;
            progressBar1.Width += 10;
            textBox1.Width += 10;
            Thread.Sleep(25);
        }
        //this.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

This is only an example, my code is way different so I can not make all the resizing in one step. 
I already tried DoubleBuffer = true and SuspendLayout() without any success.
Thanks

Comment: The first thing to do is remove `Thread.Sleep(25);`. Use a Timer. It would be interesting to know what *I can not make all the resizing in one step* means (AKA a description of the actual context of the operations).

Comment: I specifically added Thread.Sleep to simulate the operations of my code that are the reading of several parameters from DB, the resizing of a child control, the adjusting of columns in a list view, the reading of filed from the disk etc. Anyway, even without the Thread.Sleep you can see the flickering, it is only faster. And this is only a test example to demostrate the problem. Also a timer anyway makes the flickering

Comment: If all your *operations* are blocking as `Thread.Sleep`, then there you have it. Solving the problem generated by the code you have presented here won't probably solve the problem generated by the real code.

Comment: It depends what do you mean by "solving the problem"... if you remove Thread.Sleep or write listBox1.Width = 700, you are removing the cause (and I can not do it in my code), not the result, and what I need is to remove flickering without changing the while loop

Comment: Change: `private async void Bigger_Click(...)`, replace `Thread.Sleep(25)` with `await Task.Delay(25);`. Now the code is not blocking the UI Thread. Does it solve the real code issues? --  If you're loading data, do that in Thread other that the UI Thread (run a Task or perform async operations), then updated the UI when actually needed. See the [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) delegate object (to use if you have to run a Task, not if you can call async methods).

Comment: I prefer finding a way to block the UI updating, make all my things and at the end update the UI with everything at the final place (even a houglass is acceptable), because what you suggest makes the interface to continuosly change (ok, without the dragging effect) but anyway I see everything change in various positions before reaching the final destination.

Comment: Then, as described, either run a Task or perform async operations, then update the UI when the data is loaded. -- Since you're not presenting the actual code, the methods used, thus the nature of the operations performed, is undefined (context also matters). You should post a sample of the code that can represent the actual process. -- If you instead actually want to block the UI Thread for some reason, the run sync code, without updating the UI at each step, do that in the end. But, without real code...